# I am using php script to mail . inside mail gmail gives warning-- this type of mail is used to steal data or suspicious link

Tags: php

gmail gives this msg --Be careful with this message. It contains content that's typically used to steal personal information.and suspicious link warning when clicking on link in my mail.

Comment: Google is treating message as spam.

Comment: thank you but spam is ok but suspicious link and this type of mail is used to steal data how can i make it correct

Comment: Make sure you have set from header 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" or use smtp with phpmailer

Comment: Did the message appear in spam folder initially? I think you are interested to read this article https://www.tinywebhut.com/suspicious-link-message-in-gmail-50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the To header is also required in the mail function of PHP.

```
$headers[] = 'To: Name <'.$user_email.'>';
$headers[] = 'From: Your Website <'.$email@yourdomain.com.'>';
mail($user_email, 'Subject', $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
```

https://www.tinywebhut.com/suspicious-link-message-in-gmail-50